# Why gravitation does not have negative entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, gravity, statistical-mechanics

I'm mathematician so I don't know much about thermodynamics, so I'm sure what I'm asking should be really dumb for a physicist, anyway... Gravitational force acts creating hierarchical structures, like in the solar system. This structures are quite ordered and in a special configuration in relation to casual distribution of matter. So what I'm asking is: how the entropy of the solar system (or other gravitational systems) can be thought increasing instead of decreasing?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I'm interested in locally increasing or decreasing, I'm sure that if I balance the whole Universe it will result an entropy positively increasing.

Comment: entropy is defined as the logarithm of the number of accessible states. In order to extend entropy into negative values you would have to produce a meaningful extension of what means a fractional number of states